# My s3 images will not display on my django site

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My web application is using django and s3. When I attempted to access my s3 images on AWS via the public bucket. Everything else works except for the simple secure storage (s3) bucket. I have this error:

```
<Error>
<style class="darkreader darkreader--safari-fallback">...</style>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DAD37CB20E79C307</RequestId>
<HostId>
tuZqmK2Ei6dvMify2V2LoGmJxJ33UemNknXnH2DM4YzfqS3MNuvmLJJVq5SmUTr5976TkWpeHpc=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

https://framann-quilting-place.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/products/carousel/SewingKit.jpg

Answer (score 1):

there are two things that needs to be done:

1. bucket needs to have static website hosting enabled

- Open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
- Choose the name of the bucket that you have configured as a static website.
- Choose Permissions.
- Under Block public access (bucket settings), choose Edit.
- Clear Block all public access, and choose Save changes.

2. Bucket policy needs to be setup to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::framann-quilting-place/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

More detailed explanation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this bucket is not public. You need make it public or make sure you have proper permissions (role) before calling it.